# Undo Android Studio Kotlin Multiplatform Plugin File Structure

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, file-structure

To start, I'm very new to Android Studio and stack overflow. I made an app and launched on Google Play. I was researching how to do an iOS app as well. I should have done this right away but I did not. So I had my finished app and found Kotlin Multiplatform plugin. I installed it and then it changed my structure to my app. It is now causing errors and my gradle isn't loading correctly. I tried to uninstall it but my file structure is still not right. How do I get it back to how it was before? Can I manually delete all those unnecessary files and manually fix the code? Thank you!

[Current file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEqJl.png)

[Desired file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tREOz.png)

I tried to uninstall Kotlin Multiplatform plugin in hopes it would update and revert the file structure back.